# Best way to maintain cascading dropdown in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I've got two dropdown list as shown below

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Products, "ProductId", "ProductName", Model == null? string.Empty : Model.ProductId),"Select Product",new { @class = "form-control" })

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubProduct, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select Sub Product", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I'm binding sub products based on selected product using JQuery. This works fine.  Now, at the time of edit, i'm setting selected value of product. At this time, what is the best way to bind and set value of sub product?

One way i'm thinking of is to trigger change event of dropdown manually using JQuery. But problem is this needs selected value to be set manually in jquery function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - your 2nd dropdownlist needs to bind to your model (not `Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()`)

Answer (score 0):

you code can be like that

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Products, "ProductId", "ProductName", Model == null? string.Empty : Model.ProductId),"Select Product",new { id="product-ddl", @class = "form-control" })
<select id="sub-product-ddl" class = "form-control" name="SubProduct"></select>

<script>
$("#product-ddl").change(function() {
    var selectedProductId = $(this).val();
    var url = "your url";
    var method = "GET";
    $.ajax({
        method: method ,
        url: url ,
        data: { ProductId: selectedProductId  }
    })
    .done(function(response) { // assume it is list of products
       var subProductsDdl = $("#sub-product-ddl");
       subProductsDdl.find('option').remove();
       for(var i = 0;i< response.length;i++){
            subProductsDdl.append($('<option>', {
                value: response[i].ProductId,
                text: response[i].ProductName
            }));
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

just edit it as your API endpoint